# Spark Structured Streaming - Event processing with Window operation in stateful stream processing

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am new to Spark Structured Streaming processing and currently working on one use case where the structured streaming application will get the events from  Azure IoT Hub-Event hub (say after every 20 secs).

The task is to consume those events and process it in real time manner. For this I have written below Spark Structured streaming program in Spark-Java.

Below are the important points

1. Currently I have applied the window operation with 10 minutes
   interval and with 5 minutes sliding window.
2. The watermark is applied on eventDate parameter with 10 minutes interval.
3. Currently I am not performing any other operation and just storing it in specified location in Parquet format.
4. The program is storing the one event in one file.

Questions:

1. Is it possible to store multiple events in parquet format in a file
   based on the window time?
2. How does the window operation works in this case?
3. Also I would like to check the event state with previous event and based on some calculations (say event is not received by 5 minutes) I want to update the state.

...

```
public class EventSubscriber {

   public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException, StreamingQueryException {

    String eventHubCompatibleEndpoint = "<My-EVENT HUB END POINT CONNECTION STRING>";

    String connString = new ConnectionStringBuilder(eventHubCompatibleEndpoint).build();

    EventHubsConf eventHubsConf = new EventHubsConf(connString).setConsumerGroup("$Default")
            .setStartingPosition(EventPosition.fromEndOfStream()).setMaxRatePerPartition(100)
            .setReceiverTimeout(java.time.Duration.ofMinutes(10));

    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("IoT Spark Streaming");

    SparkSession spSession = SparkSession.builder()
            .appName("IoT Spark Streaming")
            .config(sparkConf).config("spark.sql.streaming.checkpointLocation", "<MY-CHECKPOINT-LOCATION>")
            .getOrCreate();

    Dataset<Row> inputStreamDF = spSession.readStream()
            .format("eventhubs")
            .options(eventHubsConf.toMap())
            .load();

    Dataset<Row> bodyRow = inputStreamDF.withColumn("body", new Column("body").cast(DataTypes.StringType)).select("body");

    StructType jsonStruct = new StructType()
            .add("eventType", DataTypes.StringType)
            .add("payload", DataTypes.StringType);

    Dataset<Row> messageRow = bodyRow.map((MapFunction<Row, Row>) value -> {
        String valStr = value.getString(0).toString();

        String payload = valStr;

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().setPrettyPrinting().create();

        JsonObject jsonObj = gson.fromJson(valStr, JsonObject.class);

        JsonElement methodName = jsonObj.get("method");

        String eventType = null;
        if(methodName != null) {
            eventType = "OTHER_EVENT";
        } else {
            eventType = "DEVICE_EVENT";
        }

        Row jsonRow = RowFactory.create(eventType, payload);
        return jsonRow;

    }, RowEncoder.apply(jsonStruct));

    messageRow.printSchema();

    Dataset<Row> deviceEventRowDS = messageRow.filter("eventType = 'DEVICE_EVENT'");

    deviceEventRowDS.printSchema();

    Dataset<DeviceEvent> deviceEventDS = deviceEventRowDS.map((MapFunction<Row, DeviceEvent>) value -> {

        String jsonString = value.getString(1).toString();

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().setPrettyPrinting().create();

        DeviceMessage deviceMessage = gson.fromJson(jsonString, DeviceMessage.class);
        DeviceEvent deviceEvent = deviceMessage.getDeviceEvent();
        return deviceEvent;

    }, Encoders.bean(DeviceEvent.class));

    deviceEventDS.printSchema();

    Dataset<Row> messageDataset = deviceEventDS.select(
            functions.col("eventType"), 
            functions.col("deviceID"),
            functions.col("description"),
            functions.to_timestamp(functions.col("eventDate"), "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").as("eventDate"),
            functions.col("deviceModel"),
            functions.col("pingRate"))
            .select("eventType", "deviceID", "description", "eventDate", "deviceModel", "pingRate");

    messageDataset.printSchema();

    Dataset<Row> devWindowDataset = messageDataset.withWatermark("eventDate", "10 minutes")
            .groupBy(functions.col("deviceID"),
                    functions.window(
                            functions.col("eventDate"), "10 minutes", "5 minutes"))
            .count();

    devWindowDataset.printSchema();

    StreamingQuery query = devWindowDataset.writeStream().outputMode("append")
            .format("parquet")
            .option("truncate", "false")
            .option("path", "<MY-PARQUET-FILE-OUTPUT-LOCATION>")
            .start();

    query.awaitTermination();
}}
```

...

Any help or direction regarding to this will be useful.

Thanks and Regards,

Avinash Deshmukh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to store multiple events in parquet format in a file based on the window time?

Yes.

> How does the window operation works in this case?

The following code is the main part of the Spark Structured Streaming application:

```
Dataset<Row> devWindowDataset = messageDataset
  .withWatermark("eventDate", "10 minutes")
  .groupBy(
    functions.col("deviceID"),
    functions.window(functions.col("eventDate"), "10 minutes", "5 minutes"))
  .count();
```

That says that the underlying state store(s) should keep state per `deviceID` and `eventDate` for 10 minutes and the extra `10 minutes` (per `withWatermark`) for late events. In other words, you should see results coming out once an event has `eventDate` 20 minutes past the start of the streaming query.

`withWatermark` is for late events so even when the `groupBy` would produce a result, the result won't get emitted only until the watermark threshold is crossed.

And the same procedure is applied every 10 minutes (+ 10 minutes of watermark) with a 5-minute window slide.

Think of the `groupBy` with `window` operator as a multi-column aggregation.

> Also I would like to check the event state with previous event and based on some calculations (say event is not received by 5 minutes) I want to update the state.

That sounds like a use case for [KeyValueGroupedDataset.flatMapGroupsWithState](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/KeyValueGroupedDataset.html) operator (aka **Arbitrary Stateful Streaming Aggregation**). Consult [Arbitrary Stateful Operations](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#arbitrary-stateful-operations).

It could also be possible that you want simply one of the many [aggregation standard functions](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html) or a [user-defined aggregation function (UDAF)](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-getting-started.html#aggregations).

Comment: Thanks Jacek for the clarifications. I will take your inputs and will update you.

Comment: Hi Jacek, Thanks for your inputs. After going through your inputs, I am trying to make the use of both window operation with event states. Question - is it possible to use both operations together? If yes, how we can do that?